# UITableView in Popover scrolls out of bounds when keyboard is opened

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover that contains a UITableView. This UITableView has a cell with a text field in it:

[alt text http://cl.ly/1b50a21ca8202d22db1b/content](http://cl.ly/1b50a21ca8202d22db1b/content)

When the popover opens near the bottom of the screen, and I tap the text field to edit it, the keyboard comes up, and the popover moves up to avoid being covered by the keyboard. But as it moves up, the table view in the popover scrolls up out of bounds:

[alt text http://cl.ly/4fe64fbfe9518f20560d/content](http://cl.ly/4fe64fbfe9518f20560d/content)

I can scroll it back down, but how do I prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this is a bug. I have filed a bug report with Apple ([rdar://8156616](http://rdar://8156616)) as well as a [report on OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=491401).

For anyone interested, [here](http://cl.ly/d1ce48ec93b7d24ffaae) is a sample project that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling scrolling on the table view.

```
[self.tableView scrollingEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the content view of your pop over controller. Please try editing the auto-resizing mask of the content view and set it from top-left.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can set the UITableView's contentSize manually? So that there is no excess for it to scroll up.

Comment: I did this as well, and then I NSLogged the content size after the scroll view went out of bounds, and there is no change in the content size but the problem is still there.

Comment: I'd probably start to look at a bug report. I don't see how you have done anything wrong or could do anything more right, and the UIPopoverController has been pretty buggy during my experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but when hiding the keyboard and reloading the table view!

There is one solution for this problem! What you have to do is first hide the keyboard and reload the table view or change the table view in method recieving keyboard did hide notification!

At first I called

```
[textView resignFirstResponder]; or [textField resignFirstResponder];
```

and then

```
-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notif {
   //Check some conditions if you want
   [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the keyboard will show notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardStatusForPopover(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Then you have to see if the keyboard frame intersects with the popover and subtract the values added from the keyboard to the popover container frame:

```
@objc func handleKeyboardStatusForPopover(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if keyboardSize.intersects((self.resultPopOverTableViewController!.view.superview!.superview!.frame).insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 60)) {
            let popOverContainer = viewControllerDisplayedbyPopover?.view.superview!.superview!
            // cellDisplayingDetailInfo = sourceview of popover  
            popOverContainer!.frame.origin.y = popOverContainer!.frame.minY - keyboardSize.height + cellDisplayingDetailInfo.frame.maxY
        }
    }
}
```